# Signup using parse api (401 (Unauthorized))

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, google-chrome-app, parse-server

I am trying to signup the user on parse server.I have initialize the parse object to applicationid and key, but I am not able to signup.I am getting unauthorize error.I am working on chrome app. i also allow the permission in mainifest file.

```
  Parse.initialize("app_id", "key");
var username= "jitendra.singh@gmail.com";
var password = "singh";

Parse.User.signUp(username, password, {}, {
    success: function (user) {
        console.log("Yay!");
    },
    error: function (user, error) {
         console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Error:
POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Parse.com's cloud hosted back-end is announced to be shut down. Open source [Parse-Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) is available, which you can host yourself.

Comment: ya, but i have to use parse.com api.

Comment: if the init actually OK ( correct args passed , good response ),  then the signup u have should work

Answer (score 1):

init your parse

```
 Parse.initialize("app_id", "key");
```

call this function

```
 function Signup(userInfo){
  var user = new Parse.User();
  // set the properties of the user
  user.set("username", "username");
  user.set("password", "password");
  user.set("email", "emailid");
  // Create a custom field for the user (there is no limit to the number of custom records)
  user.set("score", 0);
 user.signUp(null, {
   success: function(user) {
         // return the success response
         console.log("Success!");
   },
   error: function(user, error) {
          // return the error response
          console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
 });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the parse-server then you need to change the initialize

JavaScript

```
Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse'
```

See https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide#migrating